# Python 3.9 Pygame mixer frequency change not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am using pygame (version = 2.0.1) in python==3.9.1 in windows OS laptop. I use the pygame.mixer module to play my mp3 file. My code:

```
from time import sleep
from pygame import mixer

audio_length = 5.184

mixer.init(frequency=26500)
# mixer.init(frequency=44100)
mixer.music.load("Test.mp3")

mixer.music.play()
sleep(audio_length)
mixer.music.stop()

mixer.quit()
```

The above code works without errors.. **BUT the audio is played at the same default frequency no matter what value I set in mixer.init().**

This seems to be quite strange because the above code works perfectly fine (with frequency change) in python 3.7 and pygame 1.9.6

I realised this only after i thought about upgrading my python version.

Is this a bug which I have to report? In that case how do I proceed so?

Or... is it just that I'm not following the new way in python 3.9?

In case, the file I used for testing is required, you can download from https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vd7aO5ahFBHfoT97_0RSBU4reNAWseB6/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue that hasn't been resolved as of today.

https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/2435

Answer (score 0):

Mixer init expects to also get the size and the channels, so you will have to do it like this:

```
mixer.init(frequency=26500, size=-16, channels=2)
```

For more info, see pygame docs: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.init

Comment: Even though I mentioned the other parameters, it frequency of the mp3 doesn't change. It is same as playing it normally.... I habe tried changing all the other parameters also in vain.